# Positioning Div - Jquery Floater

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using this and it works, but currently the DIV is positioned in the top left corner.

How would I make the DIV appear over the button I've just selected and not in the top left corner ?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.message_cont {
    position: fixed;
    width:150px;
}

.message_cont div {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #00C000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

</style>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    $messageCont = $('<div class="message_cont">');
    $message = $('<div>DONE</div>').hide();
    $messageCont.append($message);
    $('body').prepend($messageCont);
    $message.fadeIn(400, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $messageCont.fadeOut();
            //code to clean up container
        }, 1500)
    })
 })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<button>Message</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean aliquam imperdiet purus dictum tincidunt. Phasellus a nisi et orci luctus venenatis. Vestibulum quis libero magna, nec gravida libero. Aliquam in accumsan erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in lorem quam. Proin sodales pellentesque ligula, at mattis eros congue sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Duis sit amet erat sapien, at dapibus neque. Vestibulum porta consequat massa luctus tempor. Nulla nunc lacus, varius non sollicitudin vitae, iaculis eget ipsum. In dictum, massa id cursus gravida, tellus urna porta quam, eget iaculis tortor est vehicula dui. Quisque ante turpis, pharetra in suscipit a, consectetur interdum dolor. Sed vitae enim libero, at semper velit. Nulla neque est, mattis ac feugiat vitae, ornare ut velit. Aliquam enim leo, ultrices in aliquet eget, dictum mattis sapien. Nam quam mauris, hendrerit vel bibendum sed, vulputate vitae ipsum. Quisque luctus sagittis suscipit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button>Message</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean aliquam imperdiet purus dictum tincidunt. Phasellus a nisi et orci luctus venenatis. Vestibulum quis libero magna, nec gravida libero. Aliquam in accumsan erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in lorem quam. Proin sodales pellentesque ligula, at mattis eros congue sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Duis sit amet erat sapien, at dapibus neque. Vestibulum porta consequat massa luctus tempor. Nulla nunc lacus, varius non sollicitudin vitae, iaculis eget ipsum. In dictum, massa id cursus gravida, tellus urna porta quam, eget iaculis tortor est vehicula dui. Quisque ante turpis, pharetra in suscipit a, consectetur interdum dolor. Sed vitae enim libero, at semper velit. Nulla neque est, mattis ac feugiat vitae, ornare ut velit. Aliquam enim leo, ultrices in aliquet eget, dictum mattis sapien. Nam quam mauris, hendrerit vel bibendum sed, vulputate vitae ipsum. Quisque luctus sagittis suscipit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you need this:

```
$messageCont.css({
    "left" : $(this).offset().left,
    "top" : $(this).offset().top
});
```

Comment: Where do I put this ? If I add it after the existing jquery the div still appears in the top left

Comment: put it after $('body').prepend($messageCont);

Comment: Thanks this works, but only as long as you don't scroll down the page. Then it all goes wrong ! Any ideas ?

Comment: Try changing "position: fixed" to "position: absolute". It's hard to see what will happen if you resize the browser window though, since I can't see the code in action.

Comment: Thanks :) That's solved the positioning. I do get the odd DONE staying on screen, If I click one then another, then another etc one of them will stay on screen. anyway to stop that ?

Comment: $(".message_cont").fadeOut(); instead of $messageCont.fadeOut(); would remove all the messages. It is not the best solution, but it might help.